# subtotal suitescript saved search

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am trying to get total in my saved search

The result only shows one data(total) not count all data "total"

How can get all count from total ?

```js
var parse = []
for (var i = 0; i < savedSearech.length; i++) {
  var subtotalRaw = 0;
  var name = suratResult[i].getValue(savedSearech[i].columns[0]);
  var total = suratResult[i].getValue(savedSearech[i].columns[1]);

  parse.push({
    subtotal: subtotalRaw += total,
  })
}
console.log("subtota", subtotal)
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add an example savedSearch object

Answer (score 0):

**You need to move subtotalRaw = 0 variable outside to for loop.**

Modify the code :

```
var parse = [];
var subtotalRaw = 0; // move outside the loop
for (var i = 0; i < savedSearech.length; i++){
    var name = suratResult[i].getValue(savedSearech[i].columns[0]);
    var total = suratResult[i].getValue(savedSearech[i].columns[1]);

    subtotalRaw += total; 

    parse.push({
        subtotal: subtotalRaw,
    })
}
log.debug("subtotal",subtotalRaw);
```

Comment: their has 6 data but this code only count twice (total + total). And how code if only 1 data  their not cout total?